# Hyperlink display differs between browsers (Firefox vs Internet Explorer)

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, firefox, hyperlink

Here is how I give a url to my asp.net hyperlink in c#

```
reportHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "\\temporary_reports\\" + "department_report" + "_" + numberOfTicks + ".xls";
```

This is how it is displayed in internet explorer.

```
http://myportal/temporary_reports/department_report_20091126_11_25_56_914.xls
```

This is how it is displayed in firefoxr.

```
http://myportal/myproject/\temporary_reports\department_report_20091126_11_25_56_914.xls
```

How will I solve that difference problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with slashes instead of backslashes:

```
reportHyperLink.NavigateUrl = string.Format(
    "/temporary_reports/department_report_{0}.xls", numberOfTicks);
```